# XmlDocument | Updating nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, updating

I'm starting to build a Youtube player and I have an XmlDocument object to store the video's meta information, but I'm having some issues figuring out how to update the XmlDocument.

Here's my code so far:

```
public void UpdateVideo(string video_id, string title, string download_url)
{
    if (this.DownloadExists(video_id))
    {
        XmlNodeList Videos = Document.GetElementsByTagName(video_id);

        if (Videos.Count == 1) 
        {
            XmlNode Video = Videos[0];

            //Update the Title
            XmlNodeList Properties = Video.ChildNodes;

            //Title
            foreach (XmlNode Property in Properties) 
            {
                switch (Property.Name.ToLower()) 
                {
                    case "title":
                        Property.InnerText = title;
                    break;
                    case "download_url":
                        Property.InnerText = download_url;
                    break;
                }

                //Update the property back to Video object......
                //Update the Video back to the Videos etc.......

            }
        }
        Document.Save(StorageFile);
    }
}
```

This is basically a small `VideoStorage` Class, that reads/writes to an Xml Document.

Sample XML Data is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<videos>
    <pqky5B179nM>
        <id>pqky5B179nM</id>
        <title>will.i.am, Nicki Minaj - Check It Out</title>
        <videod_url>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqky5B179nM</videod_url>
    </pqky5B179nM>
</videos>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: so whats the problem? How does it NOT update?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is more readable for you:

```
    Private Sub SaveItem(ByVal Title As String, ByVal GroupData As String)
            'Save Data in an XML file (Timo Böhme, www.goldengel.ch)
            Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(TB.SystemMain.AppPath & "ButtonLayout.xml") 'Define the file to write in
            Dim writer As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(fi.FullName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) 'create new XML reader class


            writer.WriteStartDocument() 'start writing Xml document

                    writer.WriteStartElement("PositionInfos") 'go or create to PositionInfos tag

                    writer.WriteStartElement("PositionInfo") 'go or create to PositionInfo tag
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("Title", Title) 'write attribut Title
                            writer.WriteAttributeString("GroupData", GroupData) 'write attribut GroupData
                    writer.WriteEndElement() 'close PositionInfo tag

            writer.WriteEndElement() 'close PositionInfos tag
            writer.WriteEndDocument() 'close document tag

            writer.Flush() 'write to disk
            writer.Close() 'close file
    End Sub
```